# using jQuery for autocomplete in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I am trying to implement auto-complete on an open-ended text question in Qualtrics using jQuery but I am not sure how to make it work.

At the moment, I tried using [this jQuery example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) to add the javascript listed in the  into the Qualtrics "Look & Feel --> Advanced"

```
<script>$.noConflict();</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

I also added the following js to the body of the question, but it still does not work.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#QID15 .InputText" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});
});
```

I am not very familiar with javascript and am struggling to figure out what goes where in Qualtrics. Any help or reference is would be greatly appreciated.

(In case you are wondering, I cannot simply implement this as a multiple choice type question in Qualtrics because there are hundreds of choices (i.e. list of departments in a school) and having an open-ended text field makes analyzing categories difficult.)

Comment: Have you included both `jQuery.js` as well as `jQuery.ui.js` via  a script tag that appears prior to your above script declarations? Also, the first call to `autocomplete` has a selector selecting `$('#tags')` whereas the second selector is `$('#QID15 .InputText')`. Which one is correct?

Comment: It worked! All of the suggestions were very helpful, especially the last one. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included both jQuery.js as well as jQuery.ui.js via a script tag that appears prior to your above script declarations? Also, the first call to autocomplete has a selector selecting $('#tags') whereas the second selector is $('#QID15 .InputText'). Make sure you are using the correct selector.